# Other causes of this Active Directory error?

Tags: c#, azure, active-directory

I'm trying to use Microsoft AD Azure to log into my web app. I'm using OWIN and have managed to get to the login page - type in the credentials (including an Azure admin credentials) and I get this lovely message:

> AADSTS90093: This application requires application permissions to another application. Consent for application permissions can only be performed by an administrator. Sign out and sign in as an administrator or contact one of your organization's administrators.

I'm not sure what else I can do as it's a very specific error but I've already given it full admin.

---

Edit - Solved! Although it might be a bit different than for others as it's a bit of a rare case. I was pointing at the wrong version of AD where only the CEO of the business had global admin permissions. Once I had pointed it to a different version of AD (the dev AD - not the corporate AD) everything worked.

Comment: It means your app requires permissions on e.g. the Azure AD Graph API which require admin privileges on the directory to approve. Make sure you are signing in as an admin user in the directory.

Comment: In "Required Permissions"  - I've given it both full access to Windows Azure Active Directory and Microsoft Graph. Still no luck - is there anything else that a simple login might need?

Comment: A simple login only needs one permission on Azure AD. That is *Sign in and read user profile*. It doesn't require admin permissions. If you add others which require admin privileges, then you have to sign in as admin first time.

Comment: I've signed in as an admin and that still results in this error regardless. When I took those permissions off the error was - "User cannot consent to web app requesting user impersonation as an app permission."

Answer (score 1):

Your application requires Admin consent. Try the **Grant Permissions** button in Azure new portal. Wait a few minutes for it to take effect.
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6QuM.png)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error message, your app have assigned the application permission to the app which requires the Azure Active Directory admin to give the consent.

You can check the permission like figure below and remove all unnecessary permissions if your app doesn't use.
[image]

You can also refer the code sample [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect) to integrate Azure AD with web app.

In addition, if we are developing a single tenant app and register the app from Azure classic portal or new portal, there is no need to grant the permission from the web app. The permission already be granted when we register the app.

Please let me know if it helps.